# If $A \times B$ is closed in $(X \times Y, \mathcal{T}_{X\times Y})$ then $A$ is closed in $\mathcal{T}$ and $B$ is closed in $ \mathcal{T}_{1}$

Tags: general-topology

If $A \times B$ is closed in $(X \times Y, \mathcal{T}_{X\times Y})$ then $(X \times Y)-(A \times B)=(A \times B)^{c} \in \mathcal{T}_{X\times Y}$, now we have that

$$(X \times Y)-(A \times B)=(A \times B)^{c}=(A^{c} \times Y) \cup (X \times B^{c})= ((X-A) \times Y) \cup (X \times (X-B)) \in \mathcal{T}_{X\times Y}$$

Since $\langle \mathcal{B} \rangle=\mathcal{T}_{X\times Y}$ it follows that $((X-A) \times Y) \in \mathcal{B}$ and $(X \times (X-B)) \in \mathcal{B}$, as the cartesian product

is not commutative it must happen that

$$X, (X-A) \in \mathcal{T} \hspace{0.4cm} \text{y} \hspace{0.4cm} Y, (Y-B)\in \mathcal{T}_{1}$$

That is, $(X-A)$ and $(X-B)$ are open in their corresponding topological spaces and

naturally $A$ and $B$ are closed there ($(X, \mathcal{T})$ and $(X, \mathcal{T}_{1})$ respectively).

I thought about that, but I don't know if it is completely correct or if this property is not fulfilled.

Comment: $A\times \{b\}= (A\times B)\cap (X\times \{b\})$ is closed and $x \to (x,b)$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: geetha290krm's is a nice (and shorter) solution, but it does assume that the spaces are $T_1$. I have no idea if that is a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces and let $A\subseteq X,B\subseteq Y$
be nonempty subsets such that $A\times B$ is closed in $X\times Y$.
Let us show $A$ is closed by showing it contains its own boundary.
Let $x\in\partial A$, so that every open subset of $X$ containing
$x$ intersects $A$. We need to show that $x\in A$. Pick some $b\in B$.
Every open subset $V\subseteq X\times Y$ containing $(x,b)$ must
admit some open subsets $V_{X}\subseteq X$, $V_{Y}\subseteq Y$ such
that $(x,b)\in V_{X}\times V_{Y}\subseteq V$. Since $x\in\partial A$,
this implies that there is some $x'\subseteq V_{X}\cap A$. Since
$b\in V_{Y}$, we get that $(x',b)\in V_{X}\times V_{Y}\subseteq V$.
Thus, every open subset of $X\times Y$ containing $(x,b)$ must intersect
$A\times B$, which means that $(x,b)\in\partial(A\times B)$. Since
$A\times B$ is closed, it contains its boundary, so $(x,b)\in A\times B$,
and hence $x\in A$.

If we do not assume $A$ and $B$ are nonempty, then the claim is
false: if $A\subseteq X$ is some non-closed subset, then $A\times\varnothing=\varnothing$
is closed but $A$ is not.